# Schrodinger and Laplace operators with infinitely many common eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations, schrodinger-operators

Let $V>0$ be a non-constant polynomial and  consider the one dimensional Schrodinger operator 
$H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V$ on $[0 ,L]$ with Neumann boundary condition. Can $H$ and $T=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ in $[0,L]$ with Neumann B.C, share infinitely many eigenvalues?

Comment: Laplacian in what dimension, on what region?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko  On interval $[0,L]$ with the same boundary conditions.

Comment: Perhaps the asymptotic expansion for the eigenvalues found by G. Fix in his [1967 article](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(67)90009-1) will eventually lead to a negative answer?

Comment: I presume you mean "minus the Laplacian". You could then take $V(x)=\delta(x-L/2)$ and all eigenfunctions of minus the Laplacian with a node at $x=L/2$ will have the same eigenvalue as an eigenfunction of $H$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker yes, certainly minus Laplacian. Also Im not so sure what you mean by $\delta(x-L/2)$, but  if it's Dirac delta function, I'm mainly interested in polynomial potentials.

Comment: yep, Dirac delta function.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks for referring to Fix's papers. I wasn't aware of that result.

Comment: Oh, now when we assume that $V > 0$, the answer is quite simple, provided that $V$ is also bounded from above: by the min-max characterisation, we have $\lambda_n^0 < \lambda_n^V \leqslant \lambda_n^0 + \|V\|_\infty$; here $\lambda_n^V$ is the $n$-th eigenvalue for the operator with potential $V$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Note that $\lambda_n^0$ grows as $n^2$, so $\lambda_n^0 + \|V\|_\infty < \lambda_{n+1}^0$ for $n$ large enough. Thus, if $\lambda_n^0 = \lambda_k^V$ and $n$ is large enough, we necessarily have $n = k$.